# Loading jQuery from Google into an Air project

Tags: air

I'm using Aptana Studio with the following source code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>New Adobe AIR Project</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/air/AIRAliases.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/air/AIRIntrospector.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("jquery", "1");
</script>
<script>
$(function() {
    alert('ok');
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This works if I just pull up the page as an html page.
But why am I getting

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: google.

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $

When I use Aptana's Run command, or even if I build the application into an .air file and run it from Window's explorer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot load external JS files using the  tag in an AIR application.  It violates the AIR security stuff.

You MUST load js files from the application sandbox.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7f0e.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ef7